# AngularJS - Scope value not accessible in the directive Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v2EQ4/)

I have created a directive :-

```
return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: {
            statesActive: '='
        },            
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var stateData = scope.statesActive.states; // Don't get data here
        ....
}
```

My Html :-

```
<gt-map states-active="states"></gt-map>
```

Controller :-

```
$scope.statesList = function () {
        var query = {
            status: 'active'
        }

        StatesList.query(query).$promise.then(function (states) {
            $scope.states = states;
        });
    };
```

I get data in states like this :-

```
$scope.states = "{states:[{ 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419']}";
```

How to get the `Controller` scope value in `directive`?

-----Added-----

This is what i see in `console.log(scope)` in my directive :-

[image]

Comment: Try `$scope.states = JSON.parse('{"states":[{ "state" : "CA", "color" : "#61c419"}]}')`

Comment: $scope.states is string in controller. change it as $scope.states = {states:[{ 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419'}]};

Comment: @Alborz I get data from my mondogb...see edited question

Answer (score 1):

```
return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: {
            statesActive: '='
        },            
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var stateData = angular.fromJson(attrs.statesActive).states; // Probably, your "states" model here
        ....
}
```

Comment: When i console log `attrs.statesActive` i get `states`

Comment: And what is your problem? :)

Comment: i should get `scope.states` value i.e. `{states:[{ 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419'}]}`....
but i only get string `states`.

Comment: Rly interesting, checking out.

Comment: access "scope.statesActive".

Comment: Works in fiddle...but not in my Project :[

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2EQ4/2/) was referenced in a comment to another answer that now shows the retrieval of states within the directive's link function via its scope:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {            
    var stateData = $parse(scope.statesActive)();
    console.log(stateData);
}
```

by stating:

```
scope: { statesActive: '=' }
```

you are binding your directive's scope to the attribute named `states-active` so all you have to do reference it inside the directive is to use

```
scope.statesActive
```

this will get the value as a string, you can use the $parse service to get the value of your object

Comment: I apologize, the orig fiddle was using an alert which shows the value as a string, but by using parse you can get the value as an object, see the updated fiddle, and note that you need to inject in $parse to your directive

Answer (score 1):

You have mistakes in `$scope.states`. It must be an object, not a string.

Following code works

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').directive('gtMap', 
    function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'EAC',
          scope: {
              statesActive: '='
          },            
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var stateData = scope.statesActive.states;
              // Don't get data here
              console.log(scope.statesActive);
          }
       }
    }
  );

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', 
    function($scope) {
        // If states is a string got from database, use angular.fromJson(json) to parse. 
        // $scope.states = angular.fromJson(response); 
        $scope.states = {states:[{ 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419'}]};

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div  ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <gt-map states-active="states"></gt-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/69Pq9/1/

Answer (score 0):

inject $parse in your directive....
   try this...

```
 angular.module('myApp').directive('gtMap', ['$parse',
    function($parse) {
      return {
          restrict: 'EAC',

          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var fieldGetter = $parse(attrs.statesActive);
              console.log(fieldGetter)
                var field = fieldGetter(scope);
              //var stateData = scope.statesActive.states;
              // Don't get data here
              console.log(field)
          }
       }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: This is what i get in my console for fieldGetter : - `function (self, locals) {
        return (getter(self, locals));
      } `

Comment: dont use isolate scope :  scope:{statesActive: '='} and comment out the 'console.log(fieldGetter)'...sorry i forgot to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to access your scope.

```
return {
    ...
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        ....
        scope.$parent.$parent.YourVariable;
    }
};
```

And I think you need to change your HTML to this:

```
<gt-map states-active="states"></gt-map>
```

Comment: Tried this but..No Luck..!

Answer (score 0):

`scope.statesActive` is an array so you need to access it as follows

var stateData = scope.statesActive[0].states;

Comment: It gives me `error` in console....`TypeError: Cannot read property 'states' of undefined`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978663/angularjs-scope-value-not-accessible-in-the-directive-scope